# How to implement animation like UBER main Screen in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to make an application like UBER and I have completed it to some extant but the problem I am facing is that on main screen when pickUp location animation is shown, an animation is implement that lift whole screen Up and down. I tried a lot to do this but I am not getting any idea. So please can anybody tell me how can I achieve this animation. I am uploading a .gif image for getting the idea[image: WholeScreenAnimation]

Comment: you need to use coordinator layout and collapsing toolbar layout  => of android design library

Comment: Can you share some working code for getting some idea please
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle scrolls with CoordinatorLayout and use a CollapsingToolbarLayout of Design Support Library.

This two examples may help you :

[Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

[Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

Comment: Thanks you very Much Dear

Comment: Sir can you give any clue about animation which they are using here ?

Comment: i tried to do the same but map scroll conflict with nestedscrollview scrolling behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/q/36148094/2022000

Answer (score 1):

Set **BottomSheetBehaviour** class as the layout_behavior of the desired view.
Put the below view inside a layout that has CoordinatorLayout as the root.

Example :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<!--Add your child views.-->

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity, initalise the BottomSheetDialog as :

```
final View bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
```

To open the BottomSheet, add the following code in the onClickListener of your desired widget.

```
behaviorProfile.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Answer (score 0):

layout/main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="72sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lotsOfText"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />

        <!--PUT VIEWs HERE-->
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

values/styles.xml

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

1)Import design library in android studio (version may differ)
**compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'**

Answer (score 0):

The layout can be shown like this:

```
private void showViews() {
    ll_toolBar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator (2));
    cardview.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator (2));
    ll_selectTime.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator (2));
    fl_carsCategory.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
}
```

Comment: private void hideView(){
   cardview = (CardView)findViewById (R.id.cardview);
   ll_toolBar.animate().translationY(-ll_toolBar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
   cardview.animate().translationY(-ll_toolBar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
   ll_selectTime.animate().translationY(ll_selectTime.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
   fl_carsCategory.animate().translationY(fl_carsCategory.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
    }

Comment: You should describe your solution to improve your answer.

Comment: By using the above code you can show/hide your view with animation on map click like Uber